# How to install new font on user's PC programmatically using C# Winfows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net

How can i install a new font on user's PC programmatically using C# Windows Form Application so that i can use this font in the report included in this application ?

Comment: See [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with this code base on `AddFontResource`

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint="AddFontResourceW", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int AddFontResource([In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
                                         string lpFileName);
```

Code

```
      //Install the font.
      result = AddFontResource(@"C:\MY_FONT_LOCATION\MY_NEW_FONT.TTF");
      error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      if (error != 0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(new Win32Exception(error).Message);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine((result == 0) ? "Font is already installed." :
                                          "Font installed successfully.");
      }
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you EgyEast

Comment: The above code works in DEBUG mode but does not work if the code is run without debugging. Any idea ?

Comment: I can't see the font installed inside Windows Fonts folder. Moreover, the font is not available anymore after a reboot... Any idea?

Comment: The fonts installed using this method are available on current session only. The reboot will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs of [AddFontResource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx)

> This function installs the font only for the current session. When the
>   system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font
>   installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in
>   the registry.

So the best option i found is to copy the font to windows font directory

```
File.Copy("MyNewFont.ttf",
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows),
        "Fonts", "MyNewFont.ttf"));
```

And then add respective entries in registery,Like

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");
                    key.SetValue("My Font Description", "fontname.tff");
                    key.Close();
```

Comment: you should read docs more carefully. "This function installs the font only for the current session. When the system restarts, the font will not be present. To have the font installed even after restarting the system, the font must be listed in the registry." and it means pre solution is right but it needs help from your comment about registery. X copy files will throw unauthorized exception.