# A simple program or a software to install font

Tags: fonts, installation-path

After a bunch of questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714455/is-it-possible-to-check-browsers-default-font-setup-using-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464725/unicode-character-specific-css-a-thought), [3](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117090/rewrite-url-how-to-do-a-seo-friendly-unicode-custom-url)) regarding Fonts, Unicode Fonts, @font-face etc. I's unable to find a real solution. So I'm thinking now to develop a very simple program that can install/write a necessary font directly into the `/windows/fonts` folder according to the version of Windows.

I know StackOverflow is not to offer an idea to get a solution, but to try something and fix some bug with the help of others. But I just actually have no idea, how I can proceed with it where I'm dealing with an Operating System, Self-extracting installer etc. with a very simple knowledge of a server-side scripting language - PHP. I don't have any VB, or C knowledge. Recently I'm learning basic Java - if that can help - it'd be nice.

Any help or path-showing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [discussion about installing fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12376159/how-to-install-new-font-on-users-pc-programmatically-using-c-sharp-winfows-form) in windows using C#.  I don't have a good idea of what your constraints may be, could you talk more about the self extracting installer you're using?